# Problem with eth.sendRawTransaction in geth console

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, javascript, nodejs, signature

Im trying to use the following code with nodejs to create a raw transaction:

```
const ethTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

const txParams = {
  nonce: '0x0',
  gasPrice: '0x3B9ACA00', 
  gasLimit: '0x30000',
  to: '0x8b74c9f20Da3Eb2F77a93f23563F605742C37b34', 
  value: '0x00',
  chainId: '0x3'
};


const tx = new ethTx(txParams);
const privKey = Buffer.from('26c3bc1ed44e198f044309325f424734a9557c531473738c3e12ee15f08953d8', 'hex');



tx.sign(privKey);
const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
const rawTx = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');
console.log(rawTx)
```

Inputting the result in geth console gives me the following error:

```
eth.sendRawTransaction('0xf86480843b9aca0083030000948b74c9f20da3eb2f77a93f23563f605742c37b34808025a0fc64270ed2768996859287f780e3477c2c081b3b7409e38b3210f0ebab7a156fa049e2d9eff1215a8f056f02f5e7ed06f8e856ffc2745fe2443a33b97629a868f0')
Error: invalid sender
    at web3.js:6365:9(45)
    at send (web3.js:5099:62(34))
    at <eval>:1:23(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by removing `chainId` in `txParams` and changing the `const tx = new ethTx(txParams);` line to `const tx = new ethTx(txParams, { chain: 'goerli' });`